# How to remove Gnome's default pre-installed extensions?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, uninstall

I'm on Debian Wheezy stable with Gnome 3.4 and have several default extensions, which on the 'Installed Extensions' page at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ (using Iceweasel's Gnome Shell Integration plugin), are not able to be removed like the ones I have added from extensions.gnome.org myself.

These include (for me anyway - and this may not be the complete list as I probably have one or two of them enabled and thus no quick way to know all of them):

Alternative Status Menu
Applications Menu
Auto Move Windows
Dock
Gajim IM integration
Places Status Indicator
SystemMonitor
User Themes
windowNavigator
Workspace Indicator

Inspecting the HTML of the Installed Extensions page, I see no way to hack it via Firefox's developer tool (at least with my limited HTML knowledge and only from a quick look) to somehow make those extensions uninstallable via that page.

Is it as simple as deleting (e.g. for the first one) the folder `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/alternative-status-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`, then restarting Gnome Shell and it'll be removed from the list?

I want to do it correctly, without introducing problems later.

Comment: These are part of a package called `gnome-shell-extensions`. If you don't use gnome-classic I think you can remove the package.  Otherwise you'll have to remove the extension directories, as you said, but they'll get reinstalled each time you update your system. The web-based installed _cannot_ remove these extensions as it's limited to the ones installed in your `~home`.

Answer (score 4):

For me on `Fedora 26` running `gnome 3.24` these packages were actually installed as OS packages.

If I run `sudo dnf list installed | grep -i gnome` I could see them usually with a name like `gnome-shell-extension-foo`.

I could remove them by uninstalling this package and not using the installed extensions page directly. I restarted my browser session and those extensions disappeared from the list.